# Preferences always gets default value

Tags: java, preferences

I've got setPreference void to get some values and put them into preference file. There's also a bit of code in it to store it in a file instead of some random location.

```
private void setPreference(String type, String value) {
    chinesePrefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    chinesePrefs.put(type, value);
}
```

Then I try to get TotalPlayers integer (from Main class) by calling getTotalPlayers (which is in the same Class as setPreference).

```
int getTotalPlayers() {
    int defaultValue = 6;
    chinesePrefs = Preferences.userRoot().node(this.getClass().getName());
    TotalPlayers = chinesePrefs.getInt("totalPlayers", defaultValue);
    return TotalPlayers;
}
```

It will always bring back default value. What's going on here? :(

Comment: you did not initialize final player as an int.

Comment: It is initialized with   private int TotalPlayers; above both of these two functions.

Comment: 1. Replace `this.getClass().getName()` with `Main.class.getName()` in both places, to make sure you are working with the same node every time.  2. Print out `type` and `value`.  `type` obviously needs to be `"totalPlayers"`, while `value` must be a sequence of digits.